# How to Fix Data hidden in the header and footer section in the PDF generated by Rotativa?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

In my **ASP.NET MVC 5**, I have an index view **Containing multiple transaction data**. I installed the latest **version 1.6.4** of Rotativa via NuGet.
Now I can print the index page to a PDF using Rotativa. When **Data is Excede 9 page** then some content is hidden in the header and footer section. I have **tried different CSS styles** but have not had success.
How can this be achieved using Rotativa?
I have **attached a sample PDF** file.

```
@media all {    .page-break { display: none; } }

@media print {  .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; } }
```

[Here is Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jc8j.png)
[Here is C# Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1ggJ.png)

Comment: please try page-break-inside: avoid; or style="page-break-inside: avoid !important"